# Spring MVC doesn't convert link to entity

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, jackson-databind

I have a mapped entity in SpringData/Jpa

```
    @AllArgsConstructor(suppressConstructorProperties = true)
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Builder
    @Table(name = "requests")
    @ToString
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Request {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        private String externalId;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private String requestNumber;

        private Date requestDate;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENTID")
        private Client clientId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name="DESTINATIONPOINTID")
        private Point destinationPointId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "MARKETAGENTUSERID")
        private User marketAgentUserId;

        private String invoiceNumber;

        private Date invoiceDate;

        private String documentNumber;

        private Date documentDate;

        private String firma;

        private String storage;

        private String contactName;

        private String contactPhone;

        private String deliveryOption;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date deliveryDate;

        private Integer boxQuantity;

        private Integer weight;

        private Integer volume;

        private BigDecimal goodsCost;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")
        private Date lastStatusUpdated;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "LASTMODIFIEDBY")
        private User lastModifiedBy;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private RequestStatus requestStatusId;

        private String commentForStatus;

        private Integer hoursAmount;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name= "ROUTELISTID")
        private RouteList routeListId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "LASTVISITEDROUTEPOINTID")
        private Point lastVisitedRoutePointId;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "WAREHOUSEPOINTID")
        private Point warehousePoint;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requestId")
        private List<RequestHistory> requestHistory = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

I also have a complex POST-request with many parameters, but i boiled problem down to this:
Some part of this stack (Hibernate, Jackson-databind, Spring-MVC/REST/Data) is unable to map a String (A link to the entity) into the entity itself:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/commands/updateRequests", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        public void Fgsfds(
                @RequestBody Request request
        ) {}
```

I pass a String (A proper link to an entity) to it from let's say, Postman, and it returns an error with message:

```
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.hateoas.Resource` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument 
    constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/requests/8'); nested exception is 
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.hateoas.Resource` (although at least one Creator 
    exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('http://localhost:8080/api/requests/8')\n at [Source: (
    PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
```

I'm quite baffled with this conundrum.
What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Can you verify that in `@RequestBody Request request` it is your `Request` class correctly imported and not another `Request` class that belongs to a different package/library etc? Just check your imports.

Comment: Yes, i'm quite sure i have the right import.
I even quadriple-checked after you commented.